# Error while VMware Converter for creating virtual machine for Vmplayer

Tags: virtualization, vmware-converter

I'm using VMware vCenter Converter Standalone version=4.0.1, build=build-161434 to hot clone the linux partition on my laptop. It has a partition with Windows Xp pro and another with Opensuse 11.0. Everytime I try to do this, VMware vCenter Converter gives an error saying :

> FAILED: A general system error
>   occurred: Remote server closed
>   connection after 0 response bytes read

I found this inside the error log, but I'm unable to find the issue why its not able to visualize the linux partition.

```
[2009-12-12 21:59:10.406 02496 verbose 'ConverterImpl'] PropertyCollector::WaitForUpdates[5]
(vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.UpdateSet) {
   dynamicType = <unset>, 
   version = "5", 
   filterSet = (vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.FilterUpdate) [
      (vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.FilterUpdate) {
         dynamicType = <unset>, 
         filter = 'vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.Filter:session[96925CF1-6E69-459F-948B-B499168ADB0E]7C3AC9FC-E356-433E-A033-A4484BCA6E7C', 
         objectSet = (vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.ObjectUpdate) [
            (vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.ObjectUpdate) {
               dynamicType = <unset>, 
               kind = "modify", 
               obj = 'converter.task.Task:task-2', 
               changeSet = (vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.Change) [
                  (vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.Change) {
                     dynamicType = <unset>, 
                     name = "info", 
                     op = "assign", 
                     val = (converter.task.TaskInfo) {
                        dynamicType = <unset>, 
                        key = "task-2", 
                        task = 'converter.task.Task:task-2', 
                        name = "Convert", 
                        descriptionId = "Convert.P2V", 
                        userName = "iceman", 
                        source = <unset>, 
                        target = "d:\temp\icemanlaptop", 
                        state = "error", 
                        cancelled = false, 
                        cancelable = true, 
                        data = <unset>, 
                        error = (vmodl.fault.SystemError) {
                           dynamicType = <unset>, 
                           faultCause = (vmodl.MethodFault) null, 
                           reason = "Remote server closed connection after 0 response bytes read", 
                           msg = "A general system error occurred: Remote server closed connection after 0 response bytes read", 
                        }, 
                        result = <unset>, 
                        progress = <unset>, 
                        estimatedTimeRemaining = <unset>, 
                        transferRate = <unset>, 
                        queueTime = "2009-12-12T16:29:03.015625Z", 
                        startTime = "2009-12-12T16:29:03.359375Z", 
                        completeTime = "2009-12-12T16:29:10.375Z", 
                        eventChainId = 73, 
                        vcTask = <unset>, 
                        logBundleInfo = (converter.DiagnosticManager.TaskLogBundleInfo) null, 
                     }, 
                  }
               ], 
            }
         ], 
      }
   ], 
}
```

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem?